# Render lists using jinjava library

Tags: java, scala, templates, jinja2, jinjava

Is it possible to render lists using [jinjava library](https://github.com/HubSpot/jinjava)?

So far I could only render HashMaps. I'm using the following function to convert case classes to hashmaps.

```
  def toNestedJavaMap(caseClass: AnyRef): util.Map[String, Any] =
    (new java.util.HashMap[String, Any]() /: caseClass.getClass.getDeclaredFields) { (accumulator, field) =>
      field.setAccessible(true)
      val value = field.get(caseClass) match {
        case caseClassInstance: Product => toNestedJavaMap(caseClassInstance)
        case x => x
      }
      accumulator.put(field.getName, value)
      accumulator
    }
```

What should I pass as context in order to render things like `{% for item in items %}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why I didn't try passing an implementation of the java Iterable interface...

This is the working version modified to take into account the conversion when having Stream alike scala types.

```
  def toNestedJavaMap(caseClass: AnyRef): util.Map[String, Any] =
    (new java.util.HashMap[String, Any]() /: caseClass.getClass.getDeclaredFields) { (accumulator, field) =>
      field.setAccessible(true)
      val value = field.get(caseClass) match {
        case listInstance: Stream[AnyRef] => listInstance.map(toNestedJavaMap).toList.asJava
        case caseClassInstance: Product => toNestedJavaMap(caseClassInstance)
        case x => x
      }
      accumulator.put(field.getName, value)
      accumulator
    }
```